# Power Automate - How Do I automate calculation

Tags: excel, automation, power-automate, calculation

I'm gathering data through Forms and inputing all data into excel spreadsheet automatically. I want to calculate the ending balance automatically when I get a new response.

[image]

I have two different tables.

1. Expense Tracker - Gathering all expense data using Forms and gets automatically inputted in this table.
2. EndingBalance - I want to use Expense amount in table Expense Tracker to automatically calculate ending balance in this table.

[image]

This is my current Power Automate workflow. I can't figure out how I can use expression to automatically calculate the ending balance. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi the Excel Online (Business) connector has an 'Update a row' action to update an existing row in a table (I guess you would want to update a single row in the table, since there is no point having multiple ending balances).

However, Power Automate does not bring any value added here. Calculating a balance from the approved rows in the previous table is something that can directly be done in the Excel table. Just make sure you store the approval in a field for filtering purposes.